# How to customize workitems with Visual studio 2008 but TFS 2010

Tags: .net, foundation

I have visual studio 2008.  We recently upgraded the server to TFS 2010.
The utilities for customizing workitems are different for TFS 2010
I can no longer use witexport  because the command for TFS2010 is witadmin.
But this new command does not seem to work with my visual studio 2008 command line.

Is there any way to customize workitems in this situation other than upgrading to VS2010?